# In Discord, is it possible to change your profile picture via the console?

Tags: javascript, discord

I am already aware this is against Discord's TOS but still think it'd be a cool idea; I'm thinking about creating a script to periodically change my profile picture in Discord every day automatically but I can't seem to find anything related to how the request is sent. I had taken a look at the Discord Developer Portal but those commands don't work in the console as far as I can tell. Does anyone know a way that this would be possible in the client's console alone? I don't want to turn my account into a selfbot since I'm pretty sure that'd get banned incredibly fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be correct. It is against the Discord Terms of Service. However it is possible. I would use the [setAvatar()](https://discordjs-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs_client.html#setavatar-avatar-callback) function of DiscordJS.

Comment: After a while once I figured out a way to do it from the console manually. I was able to simply send an AJAX request via the console w/ all the required properties. Apparently as long as those properties were filled out per every property needed it wouldn't fail.

It's extremely similar to this: https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/370145-discouraged-discord-messaging-loop/code

Apart it's properties are different and it's instead done with `setInterval()`
The properties I found off of Discord's API which apparently work as much as plugging in the properties to the request this guy wrote.